# how to integrate jax-rs rest service with Cordova plugin to transfer data

Tags: java, cordova, jax-rs, cordova-plugins

I need to transfer data to rest service call on using cordov plugin, but I am not able to send data. I am using 
`ContentDisposition contentDisposition` object.  not receiving parameters from plugin.

Does any one guide how to make rest service call for this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, you just need to define the upload options in your JS file:

```
var optionsFileUpload = {
      fileKey: "key",
      fileName: "image.jpeg",
      chunkedMode: "false",
      mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    };
```

Then, invoke the upload function:

```
$cordovaFileTransfer.upload("https://your-rest-service/upload", $scope.item.data, optionsUp)
        .then(function (result) {
// OK
        }, function (err) {
// ERROR
        }, function (progress) {
// WORKING
        });
```

item.data is just a variable defined in the HTML form:

```
<ion-view view-title="...">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="row row-center">
            <div class="col">
                <img ng-src="{{ item.data }}" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

...

And your rest implementation, should look of this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("key") MultipartFile file) {
 if (!file.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println("You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + name + "-uploaded !");          
 } else {
   System.out.println("You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.");
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your reply, But it doesn't work with jax-rs service.
Could guide some thing like how can we make it work for jax-rs, the given service code is related to spring framework

Comment: It's the same thing guy, you just need to replace the annotations, here you can found a guide related to it: http://www.infoq.com/articles/springmvc_jsx-rs